# Adding front-end functionality to a PHP and MySQL driven Quiz application

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I recently built a quiz web application using PHP and MySQL ([www.ReadySetQuiz.ME](http://www.readysetquiz.me))  The format looks something like this:

```
When did we declare Independence from the British?
1775
1777
1776
1774

The Louisiana Purchase was an aquisition from which country?
England
France
Spain
Germany
```

The answers are a list of radio buttons.  After you answer all the questions you hit the submit button and it shows how many you got correct and a breakdown of each question: whether you chose the correct answer (if not, which was the correct answer) and a distribution of previous users' choices.

One big problem I'd like to solve with this current quiz design is people can just open another tab in their browser and Google the answer.  I'd like to only show 1 problem at a time and add a time limit to encourage quick responses, and consequently, eliminate the aforementioned problem.

So, I'm looking for some input/guidance - big picture (50,000 feet).  **How do I make it so one question is presented at a time and users only have a few seconds to answer the question?**  Do I use JavaScript?  Are there any new improvements in HTML5 that can help me accomplish something like this?  I'm really just looking for what I need to learn next.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: For the first problem just use a javascript countdown: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cutindex1b.shtml

Comment: This question might be a place to look for javascript timers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804295/jquery-page-timer

Answer (score 0):

Question1) How do I make it so one question is presented at a time and users only have a few seconds to answer the question?

You need to use a countdown/timer to present the user for a minute of less.

Question 2) Do I use JavaScript?
Yeah you can use javascript and use jQuery to make your life easier.

Also disabling right click menu and text selection in the browser window (using js) will make it difficult for the user to just copy the keyword and paste it in a new browser and search. So if they will have to type the question/keywords it will take time.